# Why does appraisal have so little to do with praise?

Tags: meaning, etymology, language-evolution

*Appraisal* and *praise* can be traced back to a common Latin root: *pretiare* (“to reward”). One thing that I do not understand, though, is how they came to have such different meanings: ***praise* is positive, while *appraisal* is entirely neutral**.

This latter was a surprise to me, when I first heard it, because I tried to figure out its meaning from the root I knew, and wondered why my boss would want to have an “yearly appraisal”: why would we meet one-on-one once a year, to give him the opportunity to praise my work? Or was it working the other way around, was I supposed to give him praise?

Anyway, with that anecdote out of the way, the question is: can this evolution in meaning, from a common Latin root, be traced through history? Can we know (or guess) when the meanings started to diverge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED writes that *appraise* appeared after *praise*, and was "for some time, contemporaneously, used in same sense". Further, in the entry for *praise* they mention:

> The late survival of sense 5 probably results from association with appraise v., as though it were an aphetic form of this word.

This mentioned sense is:

> To estimate or fix the monetary value of; to fix the price of (something for sale); to appraise.

This meaning of *praise*--which coincides with *appraise*'s modern meaning--is one of the oldest meanings of the word. Tracing back the historical usages from the OED, the path is something like this:

- 1230: "to express warm approbation of" (transitive)
- 1250: trans. To value, esteem; to attach value to; = prize v.1 2. Obs.
- 1280: trans. To estimate or fix the monetary value of; to fix the price of (something for sale); to appraise. Cf. prize v.1 1. Also intr. Obs. (Eng. regional in later use).
- 1300: In infinitive used predicatively with passive meaning: to be praised; deserving of praise; praiseworthy (now rare)
- 1330: To express approbation; to bestow praise (intransitive)
- 1382: trans. To glorify (a deity, a venerated person, etc.), esp. through ceremony, ritual, song, or prayer; to sing the praises of.
- 1601: trans. To cause (a person or thing) to be praised; to reflect praise or honour on

As you can see, in one of its earliest senses, *praise* was equivalent to the modern *appraise*. According to the OED, *appraise* was first used in 1535. This coincides with the last known uses of *praise* in this form--marked as 1590 (in reference to the value of something) or 1724 (in reference to a monetary value). I would say that in this time range, the current definition of "appraise" started to shift away from *praise*. Perhaps once the word *appraise* was coined, *praise* was starting to lose the same meaning--thus shifting it from one word to another in order to express the same sentiment.

Finally, the first known use of *appraisal* to refer to the evaluation of an employee was in 1955.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the missing link is value. The etymology of [price](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=price) explains it a bit:

> early 13c., pris, from O.Fr. pris "price, value, wages, reward," also
>   "honor, praise, prize" (Fr. prix), from L.L. precium, from L. pretium
>   "reward, prize, value, worth," from PIE *preti- "back," on notion of
>   "recompense" (cf. Skt. aprata "without recompense, gratuitously," Gk.
>   protei "toward, to, upon," Lett. pret "opposite," O.C.S. protivu "in
>   opposition to, against"). Praise, price, and prize began to diverge in
>   O.Fr., with praise emerging in M.E. by early 14c. and prize being
>   evident by late 1500s with the rise of the -z- spelling. Having shed
>   the extra O.Fr. and M.E. senses, the word now again has the base sense
>   of the L. original.

According to Google Dictionary, [appraisal](http://www.google.com/search?cx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3aappraisal#hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&q=appraise&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=V7RYTu_ELOm60AHKvYm7DA&ved=0CC8Q1AswAg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=bad5ff059518072d&biw=1276&bih=683) is based on value. Praise is also based on a (positive) valuation of someone or something.